# POI 3.2 Image Height/Width controlling

Tags: java, image, apache-poi

Using POI version 3.2

Issue: Not able to resize an image to its original height and width.
I am able to add an image to the excel file.

After adding image I call picture.resize(); method.

Later I resize the columns of the excel file by calling 
sheet.setColumnWidth(columnindex, columnwidth)
the image losses its original height/width.

Please help.

Answer (score 13):

I found that you must NOT call `picture.resize()` until after `sheet.autoSizeColumn(i)` even if you are not calling `autoSizeColumn(i)` on the column to which the picture is anchored.

Answer (score 4):

On a HSSFWorkbook with a custom font I did the following to get a logo to be displayed in the right dimensions:

```
CreationHelper helper = wb.getCreationHelper();
Drawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
ClientAnchor anchor = helper.createClientAnchor();
anchor.setDx1(LOGO_MARGIN * XSSFShape.EMU_PER_PIXEL);
anchor.setDx2(LOGO_WIDTH_IN_FUNNY_POI_FORMAT * XSSFShape.EMU_PER_PIXEL);
anchor.setDy1(LOGO_MARGIN * XSSFShape.EMU_PER_PIXEL);
anchor.setDy2(LOGO_HEIGHT_IN_FUNNY_POI_FORMAT * XSSFShape.EMU_PER_PIXEL);
drawing.createPicture(anchor, pictureIndex);
```

Where I set LOGO_HEIGHT... and LOGO_WIDTH.. to the wanted pixel size of the image.

The resulting image was not at its original ratio and not the expected pixel size. 
So I used the expected size / current size ratio and adjusted LOGO_WIDTH.. and LOGO_HEIGHT.. accordingly. Not beautiful, but it works :/

And don't call `Picture.resize()` afterwards.

See [Apache POIU Bug 52504](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52504) or [this newsgroup discussion about poi `Picture.resize()`](http://apache-poi.1045710.n5.nabble.com/Bug-of-HSSFPicture-resize-td2300077.html) and [POI quick guide for inserting pictures](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Images).

**Update**: current code looks like this, the original image is 2000x450:

```
LOGO_MARGIN = 2;
int index = getLogoPictureIndex();
CreationHelper helper = this.wb.getCreationHelper();

Drawing drawing = this.sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
ClientAnchor anchor = helper.createClientAnchor();

anchor.setDx1(LOGO_MARGIN * XSSFShape.EMU_PER_PIXEL);
anchor.setDy1(LOGO_MARGIN * XSSFShape.EMU_PER_PIXEL);

Picture pic = drawing.createPicture(anchor, index);
pic.resize(0.064);
```

Comment: Hi there, I think I have a somewhat similar problem over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28298947/npoi-images-created-in-foreach-loop-not-resizing-correctly and wanted to ask you what your "LOGO_MARGIN" and especially the "IN_FUNNY_POI_FORMAT"-part means. Best regards, Dominik

Comment: @Dominik I couldn't find your question, but I added the current used code, it uses LOGO_MARGIN = 2 and I do call pic.resize afterwards :-)

Comment: yeh, let's just say I was... dumb. sry for the inconvenience :) thx, though.

Answer (score 3):

Good solution is to use resize() function with scale argument:

```
double scale = 0.3;
Picture pict = drawing.createPicture(anchor, pictureIdx);
pict.resize(scale);
```

Comment: It doesn`t work, because "resize" crashes in Android Studio.

Comment: And don't call Picture.resize() afterwards. What does it mean?  Is it buggy method?

Answer (score 2):

Work in Apache POI 5.2

```
//Creates a picture
Picture pict = drawing.createPicture(anchor, pictureIdx);
double scale = 0.8;
//Reset the image to the original size
pict.resize();
if (scale < 1) {
    pict.resize(scale);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you just hold onto the picture object and call resize() very last, after your setcolumnwidth()s are done?