# open an application minimize in java

Tags: java, file, background, desktop

I'm trying to open a PowerPoint file from a Java program using this method

`Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File(pPTFile));`

it's opening on maximum size but I want to open it minimize

Any ideas ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/759856/poi-3-2-image-height-width-controlling it may give you some itdea. try to iuse resize property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way in windows to open any application in the minimized state, use this command and pass the powerpoint exe and ur ppt file as and argument to the start command:

Command line version: cmd /c start /min POWERPNT.exe e:\test.pptx

Java code: 
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"cmd","/c", "start", "/min", "POWERPNT.exe", "e:\test.pptx"});

Comment: Thank you so much, you are the best